# Loop through dom elements to get text and store in variable

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to get all the text content from a particular set of elements and store it as one variable so I can pass it into a function. I currently have:

```
const post = document.querySelectorAll('.blog-content-wrapper p, .blog-content-wrapper h2, .blog-content-wrapper h3, .blog-content-wrapper h4');

const postContent = document.querySelector(".post-length");

let allContent = [];

post.forEach(function (content) {

    allContent.push(content.textContent);
    
} );
```

If anyone has any ideas it would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's in the allContent variable as an array. You can also join the array together to make a string.

```js
const post = document.querySelectorAll('.blog-content-wrapper p, .blog-content-wrapper h2, .blog-content-wrapper h3, .blog-content-wrapper h4');

const postContent = document.querySelector(".post-length");

let allContent = [];

post.forEach(function(content) {
  allContent.push(content.textContent);
});

console.log('as array:', allContent);
console.log('as string, with Array.join():', allContent.join(' '));
```

```html
<div class="blog-content-wrapper">
  <p>p tag</p>
  <h2>h2 tag</h2>
  <h3>h3 tag</h3>
  <h4>h4 tag</h4>
</div>

<p class="post-length">post length</p>
```

Comment: Joining the array as a string was what I was after, thanks a lot!